# load on GPU gradually decreases using Tensorflow's queue

Tags: queue, tensorflow

I've a large number of pickled data stored on my hard disk. I've a **generator** function that reads these pickled files in batch (**batch_size = 512**) and I'm using tensorflow's **queue** to speed-up the process. currently, my **queue_size is 4096** and I'm using **6 threads** as I've 6 physical cores. When I run the code and monitor my GPU load (I'm using TitanX), at the beginning, it looks OK:

[image]

But over time, I see less load on my GPU:

[image]

I also see increase in execution time per epoch:

Epoch 1 | Exec. time: 1646.523872

Epoch 2 | Exec. time: 1760.770192

Epoch 3 | Exec. time: 1861.450039

Epoch 4 | Exec. time: 1952.52812

Epoch 5 | Exec. time: 2167.598431

Epoch 6 | Exec. time: 2278.203603

Epoch 7 | Exec. time: 2320.280606

Epoch 8 | Exec. time: 2467.036160

Epoch 9 | Exec. time: 2584.932837

Epoch 10 | Exec. time: 2736.121618

...

Epoch 20 | Exec. time: 3841.635191

which the GPU load that I observe kind of explains it.

Now, the question is why is this happening? Is this a bug in tensorflow's queue? Have I done something wrong?! I'm using tensorflow ver. 1.4 and if it helps this is the way I defined my queue, enqueue and dequeue:

```
def get_train_queue(batch_size, data_generator, queue_size, num_threads):
   # get train queue to parallelize loading data
   q = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity = queue_size, dtypes = [tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32],
                 shapes = [[batch_size, x_height, x_width, num_channels],
                 [batch_size, num_classes],
                 [batch_size, latent_size],
                 [batch_size]])

   batch = next(data_generator)
   batch_z = np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, size = (batch_size, latent_size))
   mask = get_labled_mask(labeled_rate, batch_size)

   enqueue_op = q.enqueue((batch[0], batch[1], batch_z, mask))    
   qr = tf.train.QueueRunner(q, [enqueue_op] * num_threads)
   tf.train.add_queue_runner(qr)

   return q
```

and

```
def train_per_batch(sess, q, train_samples_count, batch_size, parameters, epoch):
   # train_per_batch and get train loss and accuracy
   t_total = 0
    for iteration in range(int(train_samples_count / batch_size)):
       t_start = time.time()
       data = q.dequeue()  
       feed_dictionary = {parameters['x']: sess.run(data[0]),
                          parameters['z']: sess.run(data[2]),
                          parameters['label']: sess.run(data[1]),
                          parameters['labeled_mask']: sess.run(data[3]),
                          parameters['dropout_rate']: dropout,
                          parameters['d_init_learning_rate']: D_init_learning_rate,
                          parameters['g_init_learning_rate']: G_init_learning_rate,
                          parameters['is_training']: True}

       sess.run(parameters['D_optimizer'], feed_dict = feed_dictionary)
       sess.run(parameters['G_optimizer'], feed_dict = feed_dictionary)

       train_D_loss = sess.run(parameters['D_L'], feed_dict = feed_dictionary)
       train_G_loss = sess.run(parameters['G_L'], feed_dict = feed_dictionary)            
       t_total += (time.time() - t_start)
```

I also tried `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()` recommended by tensorflow 1.4 as:

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_generator_training_from_pickles, 
                                               (tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32), 
                                               ([batch_size, x_height, x_width, num_channels],
                                                [batch_size, num_classes],
                                                [batch_size, latent_size],
                                                [batch_size])))
```

and then using:

```
def train_per_batch(sess, train_dataset, train_samples_count, batch_size, parameters, epoch):
   # train_per_batch and get train loss and accuracy
   t_total = 0
    for iteration in range(int(train_samples_count / batch_size)):
       t_start = time.time()
       data = train_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()  
       feed_dictionary = {parameters['x']: sess.run(data[0]),
                          parameters['z']: sess.run(data[2]),
                          parameters['label']: sess.run(data[1]),
                          parameters['labeled_mask']: sess.run(data[3]),
                          parameters['dropout_rate']: dropout,
                          parameters['d_init_learning_rate']: D_init_learning_rate,
                          parameters['g_init_learning_rate']: G_init_learning_rate,
                          parameters['is_training']: True}

       sess.run(parameters['D_optimizer'], feed_dict = feed_dictionary)
       sess.run(parameters['G_optimizer'], feed_dict = feed_dictionary)

       train_D_loss = sess.run(parameters['D_L'], feed_dict = feed_dictionary)
       train_G_loss = sess.run(parameters['G_L'], feed_dict = feed_dictionary)            
       t_total += (time.time() - t_start)
```

It's the worst. There is no queueing obviously:

[image]

Comment: I still don't know what's causing this problem. But for those who might experience the same thing I should say instead of defining your queues as above, store your data as **tfrecords** and use `tf.train.shuffle_batch(...)` to define capacity of your queue, number of threads, etc. This solved my above mentioned problem and I should say GPU's utilisation looks better too (using the same set of parameters)

Comment: Tangentially related, new code should be written using `tf.data` APIs. They are much cleaner, simpler, most often faster than the old queue-based APIs.